Issue with updating person account error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, missing required field: [ACCOUNT.NAME]
I am facing a strange issue in salesforce org. This org has Personaccount enabled. Whenever a user go to person account page and tries to edit it user is getting error Required field is missing [Account.Name].
This account has Name field populated and i have checked debug logs also there is no dml happening in logs.
I also tried to update the account record using the developer console and got same error. REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, missing required field: [ACCOUNT.NAME]: [ACCOUNT.NAME]
This org has some managed packages installed of dupcheck and FinacialForce so some triggers are running but in debug logs there is no dml count shown.

You will have to check for code snippets where name is getting modified in beforeUpdate triggers/flow.

@NagendraSingh yes i tried checking that and didn't found any. Was just checking if there is some special  handling of person account. this org just has too many flows and process builders i will try to go through them once again and try to figure it out . thanks

Would suspect that some type of automation is updating the account name to a null value. Most likely this is caused by some piece of automation not properly handling person accounts. For your normal accounts do you have a process in place to standardize account names? Suspect that you can find the issue here if not you are going to have to examine all workflow, process builder, flows, and triggers to see what is causing this to be null.
believe this is a duplicate of the following question account name - field value required issue

yes i suspect the same so will go through code and flows again.
